# Login cookies set as wrong domain

Tags: plugins, login, cookies

I'm building a plugin that allows oauth2 logins from providers (eg google). My code is setting the `wordpress_logged_in_{$hash}` cookie domain as `/wp-admin`, for some reason, whereas using the normal wordpress login the domain for that cookie is `/`. This means that when I log out, wordpress tries to clear the cookie with `/` domain. So for anybody using my plugin they will stay logged in. The code I'm using to programatically login the user is:

```
//get user
$user = get_userdata( $user_id );
if ( !$user || ( !get_class( $user ) == 'WP_User' ) )
    continue;
//login
wp_set_current_user( $user->data->ID, $user->data->user_login );
wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->data->ID );
do_action( 'wp_login', $user->data->user_login );
//redirect to admin page
wp_redirect( admin_url() );
```

My code should work, according to:
http://kuttler.eu/code/log-in-a-wordpress-user-programmatically/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/10041701

issue seems to be with `wp_set_auth_cookie()` - completely at a loss here so any help is appreciated,
daithi